# Voice or Audio player for .amr file in Java ME

Tags: java-me, midp, mmapi, audio-player

I am working on audio recording in Nokia S40 series mobiles. I am able to record the message, but I am not able to play the recorded audio message.

Can anyone help me how to code for voice player for recorded .amr audio files?
Did any one come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example of recording and playing sound,

```
public class VoiceRecordMidlet extends MIDlet {
      private Display display;

      public void startApp() {
            display = Display.getDisplay(this);
            display.setCurrent(new VoiceRecordForm());
      }

      public void pauseApp() {
      }

      public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
            notifyDestroyed();
      }
}

class VoiceRecordForm extends Form implements CommandListener {
      private StringItem message;
      private StringItem errormessage;
      private final Command record, play;
      private Player player;
      private byte[] recordedAudioArray = null;
      public VoiceRecordForm() {
            super("Recording Audio");
            message = new StringItem("", "Select Record to start recording.");
            this.append(message);
            errormessage = new StringItem("", "");
            this.append(errormessage);
            record = new Command("Record", Command.OK, 0);
            this.addCommand(record);
            play = new Command("Play", Command.BACK, 0);
            this.addCommand(play);
            this.setCommandListener(this);
      }
      public void commandAction(Command comm, Displayable disp) {
            if (comm == record) {
                  Thread t = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                              try {
                                    player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio");
                                    player.realize();
                                    RecordControl rc = (RecordControl) player.getControl("RecordControl");
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    rc.setRecordStream(output);
                                    rc.startRecord();
                                    player.start();
                                    message.setText("Recording...");
                                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                                    message.setText("Recording Done!");
                                    rc.commit();
                                    recordedAudioArray = output.toByteArray();
                                    player.close();
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                    errormessage.setLabel("Error");
                                    errormessage.setText(e.toString());
                              }
                        }
                  };
                  t.start();

            }
            else if (comm == play) {
                  try {
                        ByteArrayInputStream recordedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(recordedAudioArray);
                        Player p2 = Manager.createPlayer(recordedInputStream, "audio/basic");
                        p2.prefetch();
                        p2.start();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                        errormessage.setLabel("Error");
                        errormessage.setText(e.toString());
                  }
            }
      }
}
```